# Im gettgin an error in this code (x is not a member of a structure or union)

Tags: c

The code below is supposed to allow me to scan 3 properties ("matnr, vol, pos") in 2 pointers (p,q) and print them out, but it tells me that the lines where i scanf into &p->matnr are false. (Matnr is not a member of a strucutre or union). Does anyone have a solution?

```
struct s_box{
        int matnr;
        int vol;
        int pos;
}p,q;

int kisten() {
    struct s_box* pt_box;
    short int *p;
    short int *q;
    *p = malloc ( sizeof(pt_box));
    *q = malloc ( sizeof(pt_box));

    printf("Materialnummer Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->matnr);

    printf("Volumen Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->vol);

    printf("Position Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->pos);

    printf("Materialnummer Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&q->matnr);

    printf("Volumen Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&q->vol);

    printf("Position Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&q->pos);

    printf("\t Kiste 1 \t Kiste 2");
    printf("Materialnr. \t %d \t %d",p->matnr,q->matnr);
    printf("Volumen \t %d \t %d",p->vol,q->vol);
    printf("Position \t %d \t %d",p->pos,q->pos);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Your pointers are `short int*`s. Of course, a short int doesn't have a `matnr`,  a `vol` or a `pos`. And __dont__ dereference your pointers when `malloc`ing.

Comment: Sorry, could u give me a more specific answer or a possible solution? I just started with C 2 days ago :(

Comment: your `struct s_box` and `short int*` variable are same, declare different variables

Comment: what for example?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up structures, pointers to structures, and integers. You have `p` and `q` defined twice; up at the top as global structures, and in the function as `short int` pointers. You should either drop the `p` and `q` in the `struct` definition or drop the `short int` definition and modify the globals to be pointers (`*p`, `*q`). And by "don't dereference during the malloc" @tkausl means on the left-hand side don't use the `*`, because `p` and `q` are not pointers to pointers, but uninitialized pointers, which will cause a memory violation. You're getting the error because `p` is defined as a pointer to a `short int`, not a pointer to your structure. Try this:

```c
struct s_box {
        int matnr;
        int vol;
        int pos;
} *p, *q;

int kisten() {
    struct s_box* pt_box;

    p = malloc (sizeof(*p)); /* or sizeof struct s_box */
    q = malloc (sizeof(*q));

    if (p == NULL || q == NULL) {
        printf ("Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Materialnummer Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&p->matnr);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by this section:

```
int kisten() {
    struct s_box* pt_box;
    short int *p; // You define an int pointer
    short int *q; // You define another int pointer
    *p = malloc ( sizeof(pt_box)); // You don't have to allocate new memory the compiler is already did this statically for your definition of p.
    *q = malloc ( sizeof(pt_box)); // You don't have to allocate new memory the compiler is already did this statically for your definition of p.
```

If you want to access to the members of your struct using pointers; You have to define an s_box type pointer and then assign the address of the p and q structs. Another problem is that you use the same variable name both for structure and its pointers. Here is some corrected code:

```
 struct s_box{
        int matnr;
        int vol;
        int pos;
}p,q;

int kisten() {
    struct s_box *pPointer; // Change the name and type
    struct s_box *qPointer; // Change the name and type
    *pPointer = p; // Assign the address of p
    *qPointer = q; // Assign the address of q

    printf("Materialnummer Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&pPointer->matnr);

    printf("Volumen Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&pPointer->vol);

    printf("Position Kasten 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&pPointer->pos);

    printf("Materialnummer Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&qPointer->matnr);

    printf("Volumen Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&qPointer->vol);

    printf("Position Kasten 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&qPointer->pos);

    printf("\t Kiste 1 \t Kiste 2");
    printf("Materialnr. \t %d \t %d",pPointer->matnr,qPointer->matnr);
    printf("Volumen \t %d \t %d",pPointer->vol,qPointer->vol);
    printf("Position \t %d \t %d",pPointer->pos,qPointer->pos);
    return 0;
};
```